# Freetype manpage not available

Tags: c, freetype, manpage, freetype2

Is there any way to get freetype man pages?

I can't find them and have to use the documentation on the web.
The problem is when I don't have internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freetype doesn't provide man pages. Only html documentation.

You can download it from [here](https://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/) (see the archives that have "-doc" in their name).